# Use One User Account for Snow Leopard and Lion (Partitioned)

Tags: snow-leopard, macos

I'm thinking about partitioning my MBP (late 2008) to dual boot Snow Leopard and Lion. I found [an article about running both OSes](http://www.totalapps.net/mac/migrate-safely-to-os-x-lion-make-old-user-accounts-work-in-the-new-os/), and using the SL user account for both SL and Lion.

Should I trust it? Is it safe?

Comment: Anyone tried this now that Lion is out? Running into any Preference mismatches with Mail, or any other apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment Lion is still in pre-release phase, so I would not deem it to be safe nor trustworthy (until its officially released).   Even Apple's own guidelines for installing pre-release operating systems to testers/developers say to install it on a non-critical hard drive in case there are problems.

If you want to test it out, I would install it on a completely separate hard drive.  And without any critical data.